# Cannot disable SSL in courier-imap

Tags: ssl, courier-imap, poodle

I cannot disable SSLv2\v3 in courier-imap.

In imapd-ssl config I have following:

```
TLS_CIPHER_LIST="ALL:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!ADH:!NULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!LOW:@STRENGTH"
```

According, to openssl - SSL is disabled by this entry

```
[root@a10-52-79-181 ~]# openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!ADH:!NULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!LOW:@STRENGTH'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
... and rest of output is only related to TLS, nothing for SSL
```

So far - looks good.
But...

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:993 -ssl3 | grep "Protocol"
Protocol  : SSLv3
```

Same for "-ssl2". Courier was restarted multiple times - no help.
If we run openssl without specifying cipher - TLS correctly used. But how to finally disable SSL?

Note - I don't want to change TLS_CIPHER_LIST - I want to understand, why it seems correct, but not working as intended?

Comment: Don't mix up ciphers and protocol. To restrict the protocol use TLS_PROTOCOL not TLS_CIPHER_LIST.

Comment: TLS_PROTOCOL=TLSv1+ - still, SSL can be used

Comment: Have you looked at the server logs? According to the [documentation](http://www.courier-mta.org/couriertls.html) there is no "TLSv1+" setting for this option, so maybe your settings simply get ignored.

Comment: Edited to match documentation, about TLS - nothing :(

Comment: Did you check that you actually get a usable connection back with a valid cipher, and not something like `Cipher: 0000` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Steffen-ulrich already pointed out in the comments, you only disabled the SSLv3-*ciphers* in the *cipher* list. The SSLv3 ciphers and the SSLv3 protocol are related, but not the same, as disabling the ciphers, does not disable the protocol. And disabling the protocol, does not disable the ciphers.

To disable SSL in dovecot, use this:

```
ssl_protocols = !SSLv3 !SSLv2
```

Also, I don't know of a parameter called `tls_cipher_list`, but there's `ssl_cipher_list`. I also encourage you to set `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes` and give preferences for ciphers in the cipher's list, as recommended by [Bettercrypto.org](https://bettercrypto.org/) in [*Applied Crypto Hardening*](https://bettercrypto.org/static/applied-crypto-hardening.pdf):

```
# SSL protocols to use
ssl_protocols = !SSLv3 !SSLv2
# SSL ciphers to use
ssl_cipher_list = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
# Prefer the server's order of ciphers over client's.
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
```